# Number of distributions of some balls

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a certain problem, I am asked to find how many different distributions are there if one has $50$ balls and $10$ kids, with the condition that at most one kid has to get no ball. My attempt is the following:

If there is a kid who does not get any ball, we have $10$ options for that. The next step would be the distribution of $50$ indistinguishable balls between $9$ kids (who are, obviously, different). This number is actually ${49}\choose{8}$, and using the product rule, in this case it would be the product of both quantities.

If every kid obtains at least one ball, it is simply the number ${49}\choose{9}$. Therefore, the final number of distributions would be, using the sum rule since both events are mutually exclusive $10 \cdot{{49}\choose{8}} + {{49}\choose{9}}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Makes sense.${}{}{}$